# Converting Clojure data structures to Java collections

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, clojure

What is the Clojure-idiomatic way to convert a data structure to a Java collection, specifically:

- `[]` to a `java.util.ArrayList`
- `{}` to a `java.util.HashMap`
- `#{}` to a `java.util.HashSet`
- `()` to a `java.util.LinkedList`

Is there a clojure.contrib library to do this?

**USE CASE**: In order to ease Clojure into my organization, I am considering writing a unit-test suite for an all-Java REST server in Clojure. I have written part of the suite in Scala, but think that Clojure may be better because the macro support will reduce a lot of the boilerplate code (I need to test dozens of similar REST service calls).

I am using EasyMock to mock the database connections (is there a better way?) and my mocked methods need to return `java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Object>>` items (representing database row sets) to callers. I would pass in a `[{ "first_name" "Joe" "last_name" "Smith" "date_of_birth" (date "1960-06-13") ... } ...]` structure to my mock and convert it to the required Java collection so that it can be returned to the caller in the expected format.

Comment: If the methods need to return `java.util.List`, then there's no need to convert since a clojure vector *is a* `List`.  You should only need to convert if the required type is of a specific implementation class, e.g. `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Clojure vector, set and list classes implement the `java.util.Collection` interface and `ArrayList`, `HashSet` and `LinkedList` can take a `java.util.Collection` constructor argument. So you can simply do:

```
user=> (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3])
#<ArrayList [1, 2, 3]>
user=> (.get (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3]) 0)
1
```

Similarly, Clojure map class implements `java.util.Map` interface and `HashMap` takes a `java.util.Map` constructor argument. So:

```
user=> (java.util.HashMap. {"a" 1 "b" 2})
#<HashMap {b=2, a=1}>
user=> (.get (java.util.HashMap. {"a" 1 "b" 2}) "a")
1
```

You can also do the reverse and it is much easier:

```
ser=> (into [] (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3]))
[1 2 3]
user=> (into #{} (java.util.HashSet. #{1 2 3}))
#{1 2 3}
user=> (into '() (java.util.LinkedList. '(1 2 3)))
(3 2 1)
user=> (into {} (java.util.HashMap. {:a 1 :b 2}))
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

Comment: Just in case it is needed to transform keyword keys in a Clojure map to strings you could use "stringify-keys" which can also be found in clojure.walk.