# How to create a string list in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to create a string list in Clojure equivalent to the following Java code:

```
List<String> cities = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris","Stockholm" });
```

: but I am unsure about the exact syntax

Comment: As a side note at least in newer Java versions you can just use `Arrays.asList("Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris", "Stockholm")`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Clojure data structures to Java collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313505/converting-clojure-data-structures-to-java-collections)

Comment: for all those interested in Clojure. In Clojure, the list does not provide direct access, for direct access you need Vector (in Clojure).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Strictly speaking, examples provided above will produce vectors. List can be produced in the following way:

```
(list "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris","Stockholm")
```

or shorter:

```
'("Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris","Stockholm")
```

In some cases this difference could be important.

Comment: the tick in front will also prevent anything in the list from being evaluated. its good to be aware of the difference between <code>(list "hello" (str "hello " "world") "world") ==> "hello hello world world"</code> and '("hello" (str "hello " "world") "world") produces its seld with the (str "hello" "world") intact

Answer (score 8):

```
(def cities ["Berlin" "Brussels" "Helsinki" "Madrid" "Oslo" "Paris" "Stockholm"])
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Tutorials_and_Tips#Clojure_for_Java_Programmers

Answer (score 7):

in general you can use the name of a collection you want to create as the function to create it (easy to remember eh?):

```
(vector     "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris","Stockholm")
(hash-map   "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris")
(sorted-map "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris")
(array-map  "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris")
(hash-set   "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris" "Stockholm")
(sorted-set "Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris" "Stockholm")
```

or you can use `into` if you dont know in advance what type you will need to create.

```
(defn make-trip [trip cities]
    (into trip cities))
```

and pass it something like `(make-trip #{"home"} ["Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris"])`

Answer (score 4):

None of these are actually equivalent to:

```
List<String> cities = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris","Stockholm" });
```

This is much closer to an answer to what was actually asked:

```
user=> (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3])
#<ArrayList [1, 2, 3]>
user=> (.get (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3]) 0)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(def cities ["Berlin", "Brussels", "Helsinki", "Madrid", "Oslo", "Paris","Stockholm"])
```

The commas are optional.