# Get unknown key from Clojure Persistent Hash

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

What is the best way to get an unknown key from a Clojure map? I tried this -

```
(key {:a "test"})
```

which throws this -

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistenArrayMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1518), this makes sense-

```
(defn key
  "Returns the key of the map entry."
  {:added "1.0" :static true}
  [^java.util.Map$Entry e]
  (. e (getKey)))
```

I also tried this-

```
(key (java.util.Map$Entry. {:a "test"}))
```

Which throws this-

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for interface java.util.Map$Entry
```

I understand that I can call `keys` and then pull said `key` from the `KeySeq`, but I was curious if there is a simple way to do this with one function call.

This is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4313505/3100284) in terms of interop. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If your map only contains one pair, then a vector of two elements might work better: `[:a "test"]`

Comment: That's helpful. I am checking each key value of an incoming hash against an existing hash to see if the key already exists, so it might be simpler to work with a vector on the incoming. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(key (first {:a "test"}))` will get you the key of the first entry in the map, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that it is. I guess I am surprised that `key` requires a Java object. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @nrako Everything in Clojure is either a Java primitive or a Java object. The point is that `key` takes a map *entry*, not a map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `key` or `val` to extract the key and value parts of a single MapEntry.  For your question, it might be easier to use the `keys` function (note the plural) to get all of the keys from the map as a sequence:

```
(keys {:a "test"} )
;=> (:a)

(keys {:a "test" :b "again"} )
;=> (:a :b)

; please remember that the keys do not have to be keywords
(keys {1 11 2 22} )
;=> (1 2)
```